# why pushState() does not work for clean URLs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, pushstate

I have two kind of URL:

1. **arguments URL** like `www.example.com/page.php?test=argument`
2. **parameters URL (clean URLs)** like `www.example.com/classname/methodname/arg1/arg2`

Now I need to use of `pushState();` for replacing a new URL. For *arguments URL* it works as well, But the problem is for *parameters URL*.

Here is my code:

```
var db    =  'database';
var word  =  'hello';
window.history.pushState("object", "title", "page.php?s="+db+"&q="+word);
```

**output** for *arguments URL*: *(this is fine)*

```
www.example.com/page.php?test=argument                                  // Current URL
www.example.com/page.php?s=database&q=hello                             // New URL
```

**output** for *parameters URL*:

```
www.example.com/classname/methodname/arg1/arg2                          //Current URL
www.example.com/classname/methodname/arg1/page.php?s=database&q=hello   // New URL
```

While **I want this**: *(for both arguments and parameters URL)*

```
www.example.com/page.php?s=database&q=hello
```

How can I fix it for parameters URL ? In other word, Is it possible to I remove all parameters before pushing ? (removing current parameters before appending)

Comment: What does happen if you use `window.history.pushState("object", "title", "/page.php?s="+db+"&q="+word);` ? I think the push state uses the current relative path, so it will just append it

Comment: @TobSpr depends. If current URL be arguments, then output will be : `www.example.com/page.php?s=database&q=hello`. but If current URL be parameters, then output will be: `www.example.com/classname/methodname/arg1/page.php?s=database&q=hello`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that pushState is honoring the cwd (current working directory).  try prepending a leading slash `/`, so:

```
window.history.pushState("object", "title", "/page.php?s="+db+"&q="+word);
```